# undefined reference to std::hash<string>

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm trying to write a simple factory function for `std::unordered_map`. The function takes in an iterable which has a `begin` and `end` method and whose `value_type` is a `std::pair`. The following is the code that I come up with.

```
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <cassert>
#include <algorithm>

template <class Iterable>
std::unordered_map<typename Iterable::value_type::first_type,
    typename Iterable::value_type::second_type>
make_unordered_map(Iterable const &iter)
{
    return std::unordered_map<typename Iterable::value_type::first_type,
        typename Iterable::value_type::second_type>(
        iter.begin(), iter.end());
}

int main()
{
    std::unordered_map<std::string, int> map =
        {{"a", 0}, {"b", 1}, {"c", 2}};
    auto result = make_unordered_map(map);
    assert(std::equal(result.begin(), result.end(), map.begin()));
    return 0;
}
```

However, I get a long list of linker error, and it basically asks for the `std::hash` class specialized for `std::string`.

```
undefined reference to `std::hash<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>,
std::allocator<char> > const>::operator()(std::basic_string<char,
std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >) const'
```

I'm using GCC 4.6.1, with the `-std=c++0x` option. I'm pretty sure `std::hash<std::string>` is defined in `basic_string.h`, which is included in `<string>`.

Any idea how this happens?

Comment: Well, if you remove the definition and usage of make_unordered_map it compiles so there that function is the problem. I have no idea why, though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're getting your type deduction mixed up. It's important to remove qualifiers from the deduced types, so declare your template like this:

```
#include <functional>

template <class Iterable>
std::unordered_map<typename std::decay<typename Iterable::value_type::first_type>::type,
                   typename Iterable::value_type::second_type>
make_unordered_map(Iterable const &iter)
{
  return std::unordered_map<
    typename std::decay<typename Iterable::value_type::first_type>::type,
    typename Iterable::value_type::second_type>(iter.begin(), iter.end());
}
```

Without this, you end up with `const std::string` as the key type, for which there is no specialization of `std::hash`.

Check out how real-world library code is written (e.g. the GCC standard library implementation) to see how to handle template types judiciously.

(By the way, `std::equal` is probably not the best tool for **unordered** maps.)

Comment: Thank you. I missed the const qualifier in the linker error. Thanks for showing the usage of `std::decay` and pointing out the `std::equal` bug.